# Deleted files recovery

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-recovery

I was working on my Ubuntu lab machine and unconsciously deleted the project files I was working on.

I have been working on the project for the past 10 days. Is there a way to restore the files? I do not have sudo access. I was working in my home directory which is served by a common file system (serving all the lab machines).

Comment: I'm afraid most recovery techniques require root access.  You should ask the lab staff if they have any backup facilities.  My university's Linux machines are connected to a file server that has special backup folders I can access at any time.  They might have something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to agree with @Patches here - most ways (i.e. `grep`'ing the raw disk file, using filesystem journaling) require root access. Backups will probably the most likely way.

On the other hand, you have been warned - you *should* learn whatever [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_Control_System) they have at your lab and use it for your projects. If they don't have one, you need to convince them to get one - all the really good ones are free.

[This advertisement bought to you by [Why Git is better than Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion) :)]